# prevent hover effect on a tooltip container

Tags: html, css

I created a tooltip file

```css
[tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 110%;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #333333;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

[tooltip]:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}





/* other stuff */

#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" tooltip="Tooltip">Div with tooltip</div>
```

It works really fine but when hovering over the tooltips position, the hover effect triggers too. The hover effect should just get triggered when hovering over the element the tooltip is attached to.

How can I make the tooltip only appear when hovering the element?

Comment: It's good you made this with pure `css` but there is one issue, you should change `top: 110%;` depend on element `height` , *be aware!*

Comment: @Pedram do you have a better idea?

Comment: I went for `bottom: -38px;` but I don't know

Comment: Well, I don't think about `css` solution, probably you need some tiny java script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) from the tooltip:

```css
[tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 110%;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #333333;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  pointer-events: none;        /* add this */
}

[tooltip]:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}





/* other stuff */

#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" tooltip="Tooltip">Div with tooltip</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to tooltip class.

It disables mouse events (clicking, dragging, hovering, etc.) on elements.

Hope this helps :)

```css
[tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 110%;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #333333;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  pointer-events:none;
}

[tooltip]:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}





/* other stuff */

#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" tooltip="Tooltip">Div with tooltip</div>
```